# Flink: Adding flink-sql-connector-kafka to fat-jar

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-sql

I use Flink SQL (version 1.11) and would like to process data from Kafka. For this I wrote a job from the scala template and added the dependency to `pom.xml`.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-sql-connector-kafka_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${flink.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

When I want to run the job in the cluster, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Could not find any factory for identifier 'kafka' that implements 'org.apache.flink.table.factories.DynamicTableSinkFactory' in the classpath.

Available factory identifiers are:

blackhole
print
```

If I add the `flink-sql-connector-kafka` jar to the `/lib` folder it works but then can't use the SQL client because it then loads once from its own lib folder and this connector and it is already loaded in the cluster. Then comes following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of org.apache.commons.collections.map.LinkedMap to field org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.pendingOffsetsToCommit of type org.apache.commons.collections.map.LinkedMap in instance of org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer
```

**How can I add the `flink-sql-connector-kafka` to the fat-jar? Or should these SQL connectors rather be added to the `/lib` folder?**

Comment: Can you confirm how the fat jar is built and submitted to the Flink cluster? The approach you describe seems correct at first glance, assuming you're using the maven shading plugin and then submitting the resulting fat jar with `flink run`. You can confirm the kafka classes are part of the jar with a simple `unzip` command, can you confirm what you see when doing so? Thanks
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/dev/project-configuration.html#appendix-template-for-building-a-jar-with-dependencies

Comment: Yes, there are in compile scope and added in FAT-jar.